# Unicode with MAX7219

Tags: c, unicode, arduino

I'm trying to implement Asian symbols with my max7219 and using the 8x8 led displays.
I've had a look online and I've found libraries for the max7219 but it is only in ASCII.  I was wondering if there was an easy way of implementing using a UNICODE library - assuming there is one.

I'd like to easily copy and paste say " な " this character into my code and print it onto the LED displays.  So far, all attempts have not been working.  My other option is to use binary/hex to manually draw up the symbols but I would really prefer to make it easy for the user to copy and paste any character and it prints onto the LEDs. Or will I have to create my own Arduino Library?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Many thanks.

Comment: And just how do you expect that symbol to look on a 7-segment LED display? It will look like unrecognisable crap. I would guess that's probably why there is no such library available.

Comment: There's no pixels here. MAX7219 is a 7-segment LED display driver.

Comment: 8x8 led display is no [7-segment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5Qup8lfPug) display. The height is the biggest problem. Guess 10x10 is the absolute minimum to display that character.

Comment: @Lundin: While the '7219 can be used to drive 8 7-segment (plus decimal point) displays at once, it can also be used to drive a 8x8 matrix.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Doesn't really matter, you'll still get something that looks like crap.

Comment: @Lundin: Because of pixels.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Also wouldn't you need one MAX IC per letter? The BOM will be steep if you want lets say 8 letters. I would use a character-based LCD instead.

Comment: @Lundin: You could multiplex each 8x8 matrix with MOSFETs, but the timing might be tricky. But you can get the chips cheap enough in bulk.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Perhaps, though that seems needlessly complicated. Even if you could get it working, it eats up 8 pins on the CPU not counting SPI data & clock lines. Unless you add a multiplexer = even more components and more complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Unicode is that it's just so damn big (the first kana is U+3041), and most Arduinos have not nearly enough flash to store all the characters required.

My recommendation is to use an 8-bit encoding that maps to all the characters you need. I suggest starting with the character set used by the HD44780UA00 and replacing the characters where they make sense. Since some other libraries already use this set it won't be a huge leap to use them with your display.

[image: HD44780UA00 charmap]

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy and paste a CHARACTER in a 8x8 matrix.

You have to find an 8x8 matrix of your font (katakana, kanji, etc.), and build an array that contains all the characters in a bit-by-bit format.

To all who have commented that MAX7219 is a 7-segment display, I want to say that MAX7219 is an IC which contains a buffer of 8x8 bit. You can use it to drive an 8x8 LED matrix, or an 8-in-line 7-segments (plus a decimal point) display, or anything else.

Comment: thanks for that! this is the type of answer I'm looking for.  And yes, I totally agree with you.  I've been using a MAX7219 IC to drive multiple LEDs for a while.  I don't know why they say it doesn't work.